# aws - error calling sms document through system manager automation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge, aws-ssm

I have an event rule in eventbridge to trigger a ssm automation document and when the event rule tries to trigger the ssm document, it gives invalid document error even tough the document already exists.

null (Service: AWSSimpleSystemsManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidDocument; Request ID: bfe4614d-e098-4dce-974b-8d5a986d66e5; Proxy: null)

Comment: Well, what document are you trying to run?

Comment: trying to run a ssm automation document, which will run shells cript